# Vue js vuelidate cannot read custom validation inside the dynamic validation schema

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

[image]

I have this UI. If user check the `All dates` it will set the Boolean variable `is_all_dates` to `true`.So that means user don't care a date range he/she wants all the data without filter it by a date range.

On the other hand if user doesn't check the `All dates` I need to validate 3 things.

1. He/she enter a from date (**required**)
2. He/she enter a to date (**required**)
3. From date < To date (**custom validator**)

For achieve this requirement I use dynamic validation schema.

I only need validate if `All dates` is equals to false. otherwise I don't need validations at all.

```
validations() {
        if (!this.is_all_dates) {
          return {
            from: {
              required
            },
            to: {
              required,
              date_greather_than
            }
          };
        }
      },
```

I declare my `date_greather_than` validation like this.

```
<script>
    const date_greather_than = (value, vm) => {
      let from = new Date(vm.from);
      let to = new Date(value);
      return from < to;
    };
    export defaults:{
        validations(){},
        data(){return{}}
    }
</script>
```

But the problem is I got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'date_greather_than' of undefined

My custom validator is not recognize inside the validations() function

I can use the keyword `this` like this. It's syntax error.

```
to: {
                  required,
                  this.date_greather_than
                }
```

Comment: code you provide the whole code that contains that?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim what do you mean?

Comment: code like that in `App.vue` in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/w2n99onq78

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have another boolean variable called `is_all_dates`. If that `is_all_dates == false` then only I need to this happen. The problem comes when I use the if statement.

Comment: could you provide your data object,some of your template and explain more your use case, i could give a better solution to deal with that

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183450/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-pathum-samararathna).

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim All it comes because I didn't specify a else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem here was I only specify the if part only. By specifying both if part and else part my code works as expected.

```
validations() {
    if (this.is_limit_by_range) {
      return {
        to: { required, date_greather_than },
        from: { required },
        status: { required }
      };
    } else {
      return {
        status: { required }
      };
    }
  }
```